# Pycharm Setting up Mysql Database Driver

Tags: python, mysql, django, pycharm

Iam trying to set up mysql database connectivity in pycharm... I have already created the schema and it works in django etc...
Iam trying to import the data source directly to pycharm but i get the following error...

```
Connection to Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
    at com.intellij.persistence.database.console.RemoteJdbcServer.main(RemoteJdbcServer.java:15)
 failed
```

What should i do to make the database connectivity possible??? i have downloaded the mysql jar file for the above class... How do i include it in pycharm??? (I have clicked the install drivers button that comes as a hint but nothing happens)... Thnx...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should install the MySQL database driver [MySQLdb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/)

PS:if you're using 64bit windows,you should go [here](http://www.codegood.com/archives/4) to get MySQLdb

Comment: thought you're using ubuntu,you should install MySQLdb.MySQLdb is a MySQL database driver for python.can you list the python installed modules?

Answer (score 3):

In the properties of your MySQL connection, in the "General" tab, below the "Test Connection" button, you should see "MySQL" as a link next to "Driver: ". Click that. In the next screen, inside the white box below "Driver Files" it should have a "Download" link.

Answer (score 0):

[Check this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3C0iO1yqhk) for the sample configuration steps, if you don't have a JDBC driver, PyCharm can download on for you.