# How to connect MySQL to Pycharm

Tags: python, mysql, pycharm

how can I create a new connection in MySQL and connect it to PyCharm? I've tried to connect my MySQL to PyCharm but it doesn't work. So how can I create a new Connection in MySQL?

Comment: Only professional version support this functionality, if you are using professional version follow this . https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/connecting-to-a-database.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pycharm Setting up Mysql Database Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302887/pycharm-setting-up-mysql-database-driver)